# Proving that the elements of a free group satisfy a certain property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Let $X$ be a set and $F(X)$ the free group on $X$. Suppose $P(x)$ denotes some property. If I want to show that all the elements of $x\in F(X)$ satisfy $P(x)$, would it be enough to show that $P(x)$ holds for all *reduced* words $x$? It seems to me that this is not true. For example let $\alpha\ne\beta\in X$. Then $\alpha\alpha\beta$ is not a reduced word of $F(X)$. So the suggested approach couldn't have covered $P(\alpha\alpha\beta)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^ What is your definition of a reduced word? I assume $aa^{-1}b$ isn't reduced? What about $aabaab$? Your $\alpha \alpha \beta$ example confuses me...

Comment: Hi, I am using Serre's definition from his book on Trees. You can find it here: https://books.google.ca/books?id=amP7CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=serre+trees&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV0faF3OHoAhWCmeAKHbW6BUsQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=serre%20trees&f=false. Check page 3.

Comment: You should really put the definition in the question instead of linking us a book - if you'd like, I can edit your question to include it.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. It is a little long. Let me type it up.

Comment: Every word in $F$ is equal/equivalent to a reduced word. But if the property depends on the way you write the word, then it may not be well-defined.

Comment: You have not said what $x$ is. If $x$ is an element of $F(X)$, then it is sufficient to prove it for reduced words, because every element is represented by a reduced word. On the other hand, if $x$ is just a word then clearly not, because $P(x)$ could be the property "$x$ is a reduced word".